# Не добавляется Access-Control-Allow-Origin в заголовок ответа

Tags: .htaccess, apache, http, apache2

Получаю ошибку при попытке доступа к шрифтам на сервере с локальной машины.

*Font from origin 'httр://#######.##' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'httр://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.*

В .htaccess добавил:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Это не решило проблему. В заголовок, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * не добавляется.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 23 Apr 2016 10:43:01 GMT
Content-Length: 142072
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Sat, 23 Apr 2016 09:11:31 GMT
ETag: "1856f6-22af8-53123544a33d2"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

В чем еще может быть проблема?

**Добавлено 1**

Проблему добавления в заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, решило включения модуля *mod_headers*. Но ошибка все равно осталась.

Текущий заголовок ответа:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 23 Apr 2016 11:19:03 GMT
Content-Length: 142072
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Sat, 23 Apr 2016 09:11:31 GMT
ETag: "1856f6-22af8-53123544a33d2"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: Включен модуль mod_headers?

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade, действительно, был выключен. Но проблема с No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' почему-то осталась.

Comment: После включения вы перезагрузили Apache?

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade, да, в заголовок ответа Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * добавляется, но ошибка почему-то осталась.

Comment: Ответил...Проверьте

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade, почистил кэш, шрифт встал на место.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, включен ли у вас модуль mod_headers.

Далее добавьте в .htaccess:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```